# Jquery | Function inside same function. It bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this function for easiness, as I am going to use fadeTo a lot:

```
function fade_to(div, speed, opacity, after_fade) {
    $(div).fadeTo(speed, opacity, after_fade);
}
```

Then I am calling the same function for after_fade parameter:

```
fade_to('#div', 3000, 1, function() { fade_to('#another_div', 3000, 1)});
```

Is that a bad thing to do? Will I have speed/smoothness issues?
Is it better to just use jQuery's default fadeTo function?

Thanks!

Comment: seems a little pointless

Comment: nothing wrong with it, performance will be the same, but i don't see the benefit. You could make it more beneficial if you skipped a few parameters which are always the same, or perhaps use $('#' + div) and just pass the element's id

Comment: I see no advantage to your wrapper function.  You've simply added a layer of abstraction that will confuse the next person to maintain the code.  You should stick with native library calls if your function doesn't extend it in some way.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! You did help me out on this.

Comment: This might be helpful only if speed and opacity are the same, so I would only need to enter div's id. It's not a huge project and I am going to be the only one working on this, so I just want to run things faster. Thanks again for your support ericosg, dan, thomasdotnet, fresheyeball, namphibian, sacredfaith ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no gain to be made with your method. Plus you are using the jQuery fadeTo function. There is nothing wrong with what you did, just no gain. You could save work with such a technique if for example you had less arguments in your custom function:

```
function fade_to(div, after_fade) {
    $(div).fadeTo(3000, 1, after_fade);
}

fade_to('#div', function(){ fade_to('#another_div', $.noop); });
```

This would actually save you work by preventing you from having to enter speed and opacity arguments. You could also curry it like this

```
function Fade_to(speed, opacity){
     return function(div, callback){
           $(div).fadeTo(speed, opacity, callback);
     }
}
```

Then you could make argument saving functions on the fly like

```
var fade_to_foo = Fade_to(3000, 1);
fade_to_foo('#div', function(){ fade_to_foo('#another_div'); });
```

Otherwise there is no reason not to just write it the jQuery way

```
$('#div').fadeTo(3000, 1, function(){ $('#another_div').fadeTo(3000, 1); });
```

Comment: +1 I like this answer, except that I'd have the function set up defaults for some or all parameters. It may require some duck typing, but could really reduce the code. For example, I'd put the `$.noop` in the function, and do something like `after_fade || $.noop`.

Comment: ...ah, I see you updated with a currying example. That's another good idea.

Comment: Great use of currying. +1 for that.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad practice because you cannot use any more modifiers without applying them to every instance your function is called.  Since you can chain modifiers in jQuery, and most would agree that doing so is a useful feature, you are disabling that useful feature for yourself or anyone else working on this code body.

If you want to add any additional animations or stylings, you'll have to select the object again through regular jQuery this time.  Extra work, extra calls, no real benefit.

Comment: A `return` statement would take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is convenient. I doubt it will slow down the fade effect. There is nothing wrong with this approach in my mind. If you decided that your fade effect should pulse or blink before fading you would only need to modify your function to pulse/blink and then fade all calls to fade would then run the new routine. In this case it makes sense as it reduces code and improves maintainability. Ericosg does make a valid point though why not reduce the paramaters if they are going to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

this practice is against the goal of using jQuery as a chainable, short-syntax library. however if this specific functionality is useful for a project, can be effective.

Answer (score 1):

Mike,

I don't know that this is necessarily a 'bad' thing to do, as it might offer easier usability or something (not sure, given that I don't know the context of your example) that using the standard function given in an API wouldn't otherwise.

Actually, having a function call itself is using an idea in CS called 'recursion' which can be useful for traversing trees (you can google both recursion, and trees to get a better idea of what I'm referring to here), or performing some kind of mathematical operation (i.e. Euclidean algorithm).

I would say, that if you're doing this, it's a great idea to ask "why". You won't be gaining anything in terms of speed since you're passing the parameters an extra time, and your function isn't accomplishing anything extra compared to the API's implementation (at least that I'm seeing). If you were to make a habit out of this...let's say with a more
computationally taxing function...you might notice a slowdown.

I'm hoping to not just answer your question here, but to give you some further insight as to why it's generally a bad idea to do this. I agree with dunsmoreb, and Thomasdotnet as well. Good points!

-sf

Answer (score 1):

It is better to just use jQuery's default fadeTo function. just this.